# owl swrl rules for fact consistency checking if and only if

Tags: owl, swrl, data-consistency

Is it possible to use swrl rules for fact consistency checking?

if we have:

```
parent(?x,?y) ∧ brother(?y,?z) ⇒ uncle(?x,?z)
```

new facts are generated from this.

But instead what I have is a set of facts (some consistent others are not).

```
:p1 parent :c1 .
:p2 brother :p1 .

:p1 uncle :c1 .    # inconsistent
:p1 uncle :p1 .    # inconsistent
:p2 uncle :c1 .    # consistent.
```

Can swrl or an alternative technology be used to highlight these inconsistencies in my fact table?

```
parent(?x,?y) ∧ brother(?y,?z) <-> uncle(?x,?z)
```

thanks

Comment: Basic reasoning will detect inconsistency :)

Comment: @Gilles-AntoineNys I've tried this with Protege, and Hermit reasoner and Hermit doesn't complain when I add inconsistent facts to the rule,  is there any tooling where you've seen this work?

Comment: `<->` is not possible yet. So for inconstency detection if our case, I recommend to specify `Domain/Range` in addition to the rules. But it is only my point.

Answer (score 1):

The desired result can be achieved by stating that `uncleOf` is irreflexive and that `parentOf` is disjoint with `uncleOf`.

```
ObjectProperty: childOf
    Characteristics: Irreflexive

ObjectProperty: parentOf
    Characteristics: Irreflexive

ObjectProperty: brotherOf

ObjectProperty: uncleOf
    Characteristics: Irreflexive

ObjectProperty: owl:topObjectProperty

Individual: c1

Individual: p1
    Facts:  
     parentOf  c1,
     uncleOf  c1

Individual: p2
    Facts:  
     brotherOf  p1

DisjointProperties: 
    childOf,parentOf,brotherOf,uncleOf
Rule: 
    brotherOf(?x, ?y), parentOf(?y, ?z) - uncleOf(?x, ?z)
```

Comment: Very interesting idea, and indeed it covers the limited examples that I provided however I'm really interested in the full range that "if and only if" imply.     A simple counter example is  p3 a person .  p4 a person .  p3 uncleOf p4 .  No antecedents exist that justify this.

Comment: Due to the open world assumption what you want cannot be achieved without explicitly stating information - there is no information from which the reasoner can infer that `p3` is not the `uncleOf p4`. If you want the reasoner to give an inconsistency, you have to give it explicit information. I.e. `p3 parentOf p4`.

Comment: it doesn't help in my scenario.  I'm using SPARQL NOT EXISTS in the meantime, but believe there should be a more concise way to achieve this.

Comment: my data does has explicit information of brotherOf  and parentOf  for every person but it won't necessarily be consistent with one that accounts for an uncleOf relation.

Comment: the parentOf relation could be easily restricted to exaclty one person and thus easily checked if there's already one present.  However brother  is not easily restricted, someone can have an 0..to unknown number of brothers.